# Iterate through time interval

Tags: r, time

I want to loop through time intervals and mark those observations that are within the interval. Further, I want the solution to be flexible in setting the interval length. So far, I managed to to sth. like:

```
set.seed(1)
data=data.frame(start_year=sample(2007:2017,100,TRUE),start_month=sample(1:12,100,TRUE))
window_length=2
month=6

iteration_variable=2
end_horizon=2007+window_length+iteration_variable
start_horizon=2007+iteration_variable


data$period=ifelse( (data$start_year<=end_horizon & data$start_month<=month ) & (start_horizon<=data$start_year & month<=data$start_month ),1,0)
```

I hope that there exists a more elegant version, but recall, that I don't want to use `caret` since I need to combine mutiple estimations and perfrom complex computations within each fold.

Comment: your example is not reproducible

Comment: I just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the year and month are converted to `"yearmon"` class then straight comparisons can be done:

```
library(zoo)

to_ym <- function(y, m) as.yearmon(y + (m-1)/12)

ym <- with(data, to_ym(start_horizon, start_month))
st <- to_ym(start_horizon, month)
en <- to_ym(end_horizon, month) ##

period <- (ym >= st & ym <= en) + 0
```

Also if `en` is a known number of years after `st`, as in the question where it is 2, then we could just write:

```
en <- st + 2
```

instead of the line marked ## (and analogously if it is a known number of years and months, e.g. 2 + 6/12 = 2.5 for 2 years and 6 months).